# Visual Studio 2015 - Compiler Warning (level 2) C4146

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, language-lawyer, compiler-warnings

I have the following line in my code

```
signed int test_case= -2147483648;
```

which generates the error:

> C4146 unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned

but this is still with the data range of teh signed integer type:

> __int32  signed, signed int, int      –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

The strange things is assigning it as **signed long** gives this same error, i.e.

```
signed long test_case= -2147483648;
```

The changes below compile OK:

```
signed int test_case= -2147483647;

signed int test_case= 2147483649;

signed long test_case= -214748364800;
```

- Has anyone seen this issue with Visual Studio 2015 compiler?
- How is it defining the data types?
- How is the range checked?
- Why does it seem to ignore the "signed" assignment?

Thanks

Comment: You wrote it yourself: `2,147,483,647` is the biggest `int` so `2,147,483,648` (to which `-` is applied) isn't `int` anymore. `signed long long test_case = -2147483648ll;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is a compiler bug, *this answer is specific to **MSVC** and it is **wrong** from iso C++ perspective. For the correct and standard answer please see @Bathsheba answer.* (I encourage the OP to accept the correct answer instead of this answer for future readers).

---

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kh09110.aspx):

> The number 2147483648 is evaluated. Because it is greater than the
>   maximum integer value of 2147483647, the type of 2147483648 is not
>   int, but unsigned int.

In other words, the compiler will deal with -2147483648 as `-` and `2147483648` not as `-2147483648`. So the `2147483648` part is considered as `unsigned int` since it is bigger than `int`. and then the compiler applies the `-` operator which is leading to this warning.

**Solution:**

```
auto test_case= -2147483648ll;
```

Comment: But I'm trying to assign a negative number   -2147483648

Comment: There is nothing called negative number. it is int (or unit) and minus unary operator. See my edit

Comment: OK.... So how does one assign -2147483648 that is still in the data type range of the variable assigned?

Comment: int a = -2147483648ll;

Comment: Great! That works. Why doesn't `signed long test_case= -214748364800;` generate the same error?

Comment: 214748364800 is even bigger than unsigned int so it is considered as long long directly. (not sure just a guess- you need someone who keeps a copy of the standard under his/her pillow :D )

Comment: `signed int test_case = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();` or just `auto test_case = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();` and you don't need to use your calculator for 2^31

Comment: it would not be meaningful since it is min() not a literal

Comment: I believe the history is that `long long` was not added until C++11, so this value was correct to be `unsigned long` until recently. However,even though MS have added some C++11 support, they elected to retain the original type for values in range of `unsigned long` (perhaps in order to avoid changing the behaviour of existing code)

Answer (score 12):

**This is a compiler bug.**

First thing to note: -2147483648 is **not** a literal. There is no such thing as a negative literal in C++.

-2147483648 is a compile time evaluable constant expression consisting of 2147483648 and the unary minus operator.

On MSVC targeting Windows x64 (where an int and long are both 32 bit), 2147483648 *should* be a `long long int`, and therefore so will -2147483648. My understanding is that the standard *insists* on a signed type *unless* you use a hexadecimal or octal literal.

The narrowing conversion to `signed int` is, in this case, well-defined since you're targeting a platform with a 32 bit 2's complement `int` type.

Further reference: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: I don't see your point. 2147483648 is too big for a 32 bit signed, so the standard insists that long long int is used.

Comment: Ah! sorry sorry I get you now

Comment: You mean standard stated that the next level if int is not fit is long long rather than the unsigned version of int ?

Comment: Indeed. It *can't* use an unsigned type unless you've written the literal in hexadecimal or octal notation. See the "unsuffixed" part of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: Interesting! In MSDN they stated clearly that it is something that was done by intention!

Comment: My reading is that they are not implementing the standard correctly.

Comment: While adding "long long" to C99 would not change the behavior of most code that didn't actually use the type, it changed the meaning of decimal literals whose value was between ULNG_MAX+1UL and ULNG_MAX.  A compiler that values compatibility with existing code over compliance with a new standard might evaluate such decimal literals in the same fashion as earlier code would have expected.